# Is there a PHP function to test a zero date

Tags: php, datetime

Looking for a shorthand or better way to test a zero date (MySQL datetime column) other than:

```
if ($row['this_date'] == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') echo 'No date set.';
```

Is there a PHP function that test it? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use `NULL` instead of "zero date".

Comment: @Crozin NULL **is not** equal substitution!

Comment: but NULL can be used if the date column is empty, if it has '0000-00-00 00:00:00' stored in the database it's not empty and therefore not NULL.

Comment: @Crozin run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datepub < NOW()` with null field and be surprized

Comment: I've just assumed that "zero date" is used in case of *date not set* state. That's why I suggested to use `NULL` instead. @Col. Shrapnel: Just add extra condition for nulls: `WHERE date_pub IS [NOT] NULL AND date_pub < NOW()`.

Comment: @Crozin I don't need no extra conditions. NULL is null and zero value is zero value. DO NOT MIX THEM

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you don't need any shorthand.
It's sort of some micro-optimization.

You have already spent more time asking this question than can save you such a shorthand in a year of average coding. Just write it and move on.
Don't you have more important problems to solve?

Moreover, with such a shorthand you will *obfuscate* your own code.
Your current statement is perfectly clear, reads `"if date is empty"`
but all proposed snippets aren't that clear. Coming to this code months later, you will puzzle yourself with question, if such a code monster have any special meaning.

What you actually wanted is **readability**. But you have it already. While all proposed shorthands don't.

Comment: Hey Colnel. Long time no hear. I remember you snipped me on a couple of posts a while back. Great to see you're still out there with so much time on your hands to take pot shots at those us who wish to explore and learn. Your comments are always anticipated...keep firing :)

Comment: totaly agree with Col. Shrapnel. Why make it harder on yourself and lose time while you already have it working

Comment: @Dr the Col is rough, but he *is* right - the example you show is by far the most readable of the bunch.

Comment: I disagree. Im all for readability but if the format changes you have to change a string in the code.

Answer (score 17):

What about:

```
if(strtotime($row['this_date']) == 0) echo 'No date set.';
```

Comment: strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00') == -62169968592  so it's not always zero. Your default timezone affects the result.

Comment: maybe can do if greater than 0 instead

Answer (score 5):

Although you should probably use NULL in your database, a simple hack would be:

```
if(!(int)$row['this_date'])echo'No Date Set.';
```

What kind of better way are you expecting to find? it's fast as it is.

P.S. It's a hack because I'm assuming you will have a year set. Meaning it won't work for the string `0000-00-00 00:00:01`

Comment: Naw, for that it will work :) 2000 :-? now that's a year with a problem. But we already know the year format is 4 chars!

Comment: if date is not null it will be something like '2011-04-08 12:51:12', but - and : are not integers while you are forcing it. Will that still work? or do I misunderstand the (int) ??

Comment: yeah my bad. only 2000 year in danger. anyway it's too weak assumption and too negligible goal

Answer (score 5):

Being a fan of regular expressions, I'll add another one:

```
if (!preg_match('/[1-9]/', $row['this_date'])) echo 'No date set.';
```

- Works also with timestamps and other stuff.
- Obviously does not check for date consistency.

Comment: ive been looking all over the web for an answer like this that suits my needs. finally i got it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtotime($row['this_date'])) echo 'No date set.';
```

Comment: hum no that will take more time

Comment: ehm? You really assume, that this will heavily effect your performance?! Oo

Comment: @Manu Example, strtotime('2020-02-21 16:30:47') equals to 1582263047. Did you intented to check false in your condition? Even this strtotime('1969-02-21 16:30:47') outputs negative value

Comment: I have no idea, that was 10 years ago.

Comment: needs to be if greater than 0 rather than just if

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
if ($timedate->format('U') == -62169962400){
   // 0000-00-00
}
```

`format('U')` will return `Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)` The number may need to be adjusted for the timezone

Comment: What timezone? UTC _is_ the current time and all timezones are just offsets from UTC. If you mean adjust the "zero" date for timezone, it's there because no date was given (and therefore shouldn't be timezone adjusted when stored)

Comment: it depends if you're using `date_default_timezone`, when I set it to `America/Edmonton` for example, I get `-62169956768`. I've found that `$timedate == 0` works too, but that answer was taken.

Comment: You should mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use checkdate

```
<?php
var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000));
var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I use for the exact same thing:

```
/**
 * Like empty(), but also returns true for empty MySQL DATE ('0000-00-00') and DATETIME ('0000-00-00 00:00:00')
 *
 * @param mixed $var Variable to check
 * @return bool
 */
function empty_date($var)
{
    if (empty($var) or $var === '0000-00-00' or $var === '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
$date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
if(str_replace(array("-", " ", ":"), "", $date)*1>0){
    echo "DATE";
} else {
    echo "NODATE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be avoided at all costs to use and store zero dates. This function could help close the gap until they are fully removed from your code. May be it could be called "isEmptyDate" or "isNullDate".

```
// Returns 'true' for zero, zero dates or times, null, false
function isZeroDate($date)
{
  if (empty($date)) return true;

  if (is_string($date)) {
    // Extract any character that it's not digit and convert it to int
    // 0000-00-00 00:00 || 0000 || 00:00 || 0000-00-00 will return true
    $ival = intval(preg_replace('~\D~', '', $date), 10);
    if ($ival == 0) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

**Carbon** and **DateTime** classes cannot parse zero dates with this format "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

With any PHP framework like Laravel, use nullable columns in your migrations to store NULL dates in DB

eg. in Laravel:

```
$table->timestamp('some_date')->nullable()->default(null);
```

eg in MySql:

```
create table date_test (some_date datetime null default null);
insert into date_test (some_date) values (null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Something I currently use and was exploring to hopefully find a better solution...

```
function prep_empty_fields(&$data) {
$is_obj = is_object($data);
$is_arr = is_array($data);
if ($is_obj || $is_arr) {
    $empty_values = array(
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        '0',
        '00',
        '0000', //year
        '000000',
        '00000000',
        '0000000000',
        '000000000000',
        '00000000000000',
        '0000000000000000',
        '0000-00-00 00:00:00', //datetime
        '0000-00-00', //date
        '00:00:00', //time
        '0.0000',
        '0.000',
        '0.00',
        '0.0'
    );
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $empty_values)) {
            if ($is_obj) {
                $data->$key = '';
            } else {
                $data[$key] = '';
            }
        } elseif (strpos($value, '<') !== FALSE) { //has html characters
            $value = htmlentities($value);
            if ($is_obj) {
                $data->$key = $value;
            } else {
                $data[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code simply gets rid of the "empty" values, but may be a good starting point for you.